# Gradient on a div border in CSS

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I need to put a border with a gradient on a div like below, I've already tried a few methods but none of them work...
How can I do it?
Thanks in advance
The gradient is:

```css
linear-gradient(93deg, #6FB3D9 -0.72%, rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.00) 98.53%, rgba(111, 179, 217, 0.00) 98.53%)
```

[This is a screenshot from Figma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWZaH.png)

I've tried box-shadows, outline, border but none of them work, or I've used them wrong.

Comment: Set the gradient as a `background`, add some padding, then add a dummy child div to hold the actual contents and have the actual background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `border-image` with `linear-gradient`

```
.box {
    border:30px solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(blue, red) 30;
}
```

Comment: It's works ! How can I conserve the border-radius ?

Comment: You can't combine them sadly. You can use a bitmap image where you don't stretch the corners, see the example on top of this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image Or else you have to hack a bit with CSS tricks, you can find some solutions here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, to use the gradient in the border I see 2 ways, the first was commented on in a previous answer, which is using border-image.

```
div{
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(93deg, #6FB3D9 -0.72%, rgba(217, 217, 217, 
    0.00) 98.53%, rgba(111, 179, 217, 0.00) 98.53%) 30;
}
```

Another way, which I don't recommend, but is possible if you have a problem using the border-image with another tag or in cases like a form, is to define a background-image on a top element and create a child for that element with the desired color. The gradient styling can be done entirely on the parent using the ::before pseudo-element.

Referências:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image
- https://css-tricks.com/gradient-borders-in-css/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before